# C/C++ Pointers and Arrays help

Tags: c++, c, arrays, string, pointers

I have the following C++ code and I can't seem to get it working. What I am trying to do is read numerous entries from the command line, separated by ('|') pipe characters, and then splitting the resulting strings by spaces.

```
eg. 

mkdir C:/unixcode/shells|cd D:/margins/code | pwd| finger kobojunkie | last -l kobojunkie
```

but so far, I get errors, something about declaring the size of the pointer:

> Initializer fails to determine the size of `argv2`
>   cannot convert `char**` to `char*` for argument 1 to `char strtok(char*, const char*)`

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char * pch;
    pch = strtok (argv,"|");
    //parse the contents of the generated arrays
    while (pch != NULL)
    {
        printf ("%s\n",pch);
        char * argv2[] = pch;
        char * subpch = strtok(argv2," ");

        while (subpch !=NULL)
        {
            printf ("%s\n",subpch);
            subpch = strtok (NULL, " ");
        }
        pch = strtok (NULL, " ");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which are you using? C++ or C? These are fundamentally different. Your code is pure C, but C++ would probably make the task much easier.

Comment: Most operating systems (including windows) will parse pipe as a special character and execute your program before the pipe, and will pipe the output to whats after the pipe. you have to choose different symbol to split your input.

Comment: Why do you care where the input comes from?

Comment: @Dani Nonsense: `./your_cmd 'this|works|just|fine'`

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: if you quote it. the OP never said hes quoting his

Comment: The Pipe characters are delimiters. Essentially I want to read the string on the command line and parse it all myself, in the way I want to. Which is to first split the original at "|" xters and then each resulting string by spaces.

Comment: Mandatory reading: section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com).

Comment: @Dani Because that is utterly irrelevant to the question.

Comment: I am not going to demand quotes be put around the command line string though. Will that work still? I am trying to test this but still unable to.

Comment: No.  If the program is invoked from a shell command line, and the `|` characters aren't escaped or quoted, the program simply won't see them.

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean a bit more there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command-line is managed by a program: the shell (probably `cmd.exe` in Windows or `bash` in Linux). That shell gets all the stuff written in the command line and parses it and executes the commands specified.

Unless you are writing a shell, you cannot ever see the `"|"` of your example command-line inside the programs you write. They are effectively processed from the shell and removed from the parameters sent to the programs.

In

```
mkdir C:/unixcode/shells|cd D:/margins/code | pwd| finger kobojunkie | last -l kobojunkie
```

the shell calls the 5 following commands, each with the parameters specified

- mkdir C:/unixcode/shells
- cd D:/margins/code
- pwd
- finger kobojunkie
- last -l kobojunkie

Note none of the programs receive a `"|"`.

---

If you are indeed writing a shell, the command-line is not available in the `argv` array. It depends on the way you manage input inside your shell.

Comment: I am trying to write a shell to spawn child processes to execute each of the commands. So my thinking is I pull a string from command line, parse the string so I can assign individual commands to child processes and execute them using execlp()

Comment: No, no, no. A shell does not get the interactive input from the command-line. It outputs a prompt (`C:\DOS>` or `kobojunkie@localhost:~$ ` for example) and waits for input from the keyboard; then it process the input (calling other programs with some command-line of their own) and repeats until the computer is shutdown.

Comment: So, how do I write my own shell so I process the input the way I want, in my own shell.

Comment: I haven't read the [Writing Your Own Shell](http://linuxgazette.net/111/ramankutty.html) (by Hiran Ramankutty) with great attention, but it looks like a good introduction for writing shells. Read it, or google for other articles, enjoy and have fun.

Answer (score 2):

the type of argv is `char**`, not `char*` hence you cannot pass it to strtok. Use argv[ 1 ] instead, but check that argc >= 2 first.

Or, since this is tagged c++, use stl to split the string, eg

```
void split( const std::string& s, char delim, std::vector<std::string>& elems )
{
  std::stringstream ss( s );
  std::string item;
  while( std::getline( ss, item, delim ) )
    if( !item.empty() )
      elems.push_back( item );
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  if( argc == 2 )
  {
    std::vector< std::string > elements;
    split( argv[ 1 ], '|', elements );
    //elements now contains all items..
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`argv` is an array of <strike>arrays</strike> pointers. You cannot pass it as is to strtok: you need to pass its elements in a loop

```
for (k = 1; k < argc; k++) {
    pch = strtok(argv[k], "|");
    /* ... */
}
```

Also: are you sure you want to delimit with `"|"`? That character has a special meaning to shells and, usually, does not make it to your program.
Unless you call your program with them escaped, eg

```
bash$ ./a.out 'one|two|three' 'four|five|six'
```

Comment: I am trying to allow the user enter multiple commands, along with parameters but separating each group with the pipe('|') character. How do I handle that situation with argv?

Comment: @Kobojunkie: please edit your question and add an example command-line. Maybe the pipe character (and everything after it) gets "eaten" by your shell, or it's a separate argument, or something else. Help us help you :)

Comment: Not really. I meant something like: "an example command line I want to parse is `main.exe one | two | three`".

Comment: Done. I included a sample String I would like to retrieve from command line and process

Answer (score 0):

`argv` is not a string. `argv` is an *array* of strings. `strtok` takes a string, so you cannot pass it an array of strings and expect it to do something meaningful.

Each string element of the `argv` array is a separate command line parameter, except for the first which is the name of the executable. So what you should be doing is looking through each string entry for "|", and acting accordingly.

Comment: @Keith: If you want to get technical, `argv` is an array of pointers to `char`. That is, an array of `char*`. A `char*` is also called a "string" or a "C-string". Therefore, saying that `argv` is an array of strings is accurate. A pointer to a string (string being defined as a `char*`) would be a `char**`.

Comment: That turns out not to be correct.  The terms "string" and "pointer to string" are defined in the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), 7.1.1p1: "A *string* is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the ﬁrst null character. ... A *pointer to a string* is a pointer to its initial (lowest addressed) character."  A `char*` is *not* a string.

Comment: Sorry, my initial comment wasn't quite correct.  `argv` is a pointer, not an array.  Specifically, it's a pointer to the first element of an array of `char*`.  Each element of that array is either a pointer to a string, or a null pointer.